# Why is Javascript object not updating fields?

Tags: javascript, json

Below I have the following code:

```
var imageType = "BoxArt";
var uploadReason = "New season";
var fileKey = "b2fc";

alert("imageType = " + imageType);
alert("uploadReason = " + uploadReason);
alert("fileKey = " + fileKey);

var iVO = { "images":{}};
var thisImage = fileKey;
iVO["images"][thisImage.fileKey] = thisImage;
iVO["images"][thisImage.imageType] = imageType;
iVO["images"][thisImage.uploadReason] = uploadReason;

alert("iVO['images'][thisImage.imageType] = " + iVO["images"][thisImage.imageType]);
alert("iVO['images'][thisImage.uploadReason] = " + iVO["images"]    [thisImage.uploadReason]);
alert("iVO['images'][thisImage.fileKey] = " + iVO["images"][thisImage.fileKey]);
alert("JSON.stringify(iVO):\n" + JSON.stringify(iVO));
```

When I execute this I get the following output:

```
imageType = "BoxArt"
uploadReason = "New season"
fileKey = "b2fc"
iVO['images'][thisImage.imageType] = "New season"
iVO['images'][thisImage.uploadReason] = "New season"
iVO['images'][thisImage.fileKey] = "New season"
JSON.stringify(iVO):
{"images"}:{"undefined":"New season"}}
```

**What is going on here?!?!?**

The first three alerts (showing `imageType`, `uploadReason`, and `fileKey` assignments) are as expected, but the `iVO` object is not acting at all like I expected. The `JSON.stringify` method is the normal [`json2.js`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) method, and I haven't modified it.

**Why is "New season" showing up as every `iVO["images"]` field value?** Why aren't the `iVO` assignments working properly?!? **What do I need to do to fix them?**

The desired output of `JSON.stringify(iVO)` would be (in pretty-print form):

```
{
    "images":
    {
        "b2fc":
        {
            "imageType":"BoxArt",
            "uploadReason":"New season",
            "fileKey":"b2fc"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for sure, where you defined

```
iVO["images"][thisImage.fileKey] = thisImage;
iVO["images"][thisImage.imageType] = imageType;
iVO["images"][thisImage.uploadReason] = uploadReason;
```

`thisImage` is a string by previous assignment to `fileKey` so `thisImage.fileKey`, `thisImage.imageType` and `thisImage.uploadReason` are invalid references

probably you want to do something like `iVO["images"][fileKey]["imageType"] = imageType`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
iVO['images'][thisImage] = {
         "imageType":"BoxArt",
        "uploadReason":"New season",
        "fileKey":"b2fc"
    };
```

which I would write as

```
 iVO.images[thisImage] = {
         "imageType":"BoxArt",
        "uploadReason":"New season",
        "fileKey":"b2fc"
    };
```

There is no magic auto-unnesting/vivification of sub-objects for field names with dots in them.